# Can a willow tree be shaped?

Tags: trees, pruning

I want to keep the tree kind of short. I want it to look like a mushroom on top, then in the summer just trim the bottom.

Is this possible?

Comment: Which variety of Willow is it?

Comment: This is possible with a lot of work.  Willows don't normally grow in that shape so you will be out trimming three or four times a year in the growing season.  A weeping mulberry or any weeping leafy tree is easier to shape the way you want

Answer (score 4):

The comment by kevinsky is right on.  Willows are fast growers, and even in our cool climate (Alberta) will do 3-4 feet a year.  You would be constantly pruning.

You may be able to find a top graft, where a willow such as Dwarf Arctic Blue (S. purpurea 'nana') is grafted to a tree form trunk.  This would reduce seriously the amount of top pruning required.  But since it has full sized roots, I'd expect a lot of suckering.

There are many top grafted trees that may suit you better.

Look for a top grafted tri-colour willow.  The top 'ball' will be about 5 feet across.  they are usually centered 5-6 feet off the ground.

Comment: When I planted Arctic willow on a heavily compacted berm you couldn't even see over it in three years.  Hope a dwarf type stays dwarf. Top grafts tend to be bit dicey in colder climates.